# ISDN: how to set two channels with serial TA?

Tags: serial-port, modem

Playing with retro-computing I have successfully configured a isdn pci TA, to set up the connection I use a script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
isdnctrl addif ippp0
isdnctrl addslave ippp0 ippp1
isdnctrl eaz ippp0 myphone
isdnctrl eaz ippp1 myphone
isdnctrl l2_prot ippp0 hdlc
isdnctrl l3_prot ippp0 trans
isdnctrl l2_prot ippp1 hdlc
isdnctrl l3_prot ippp1 trans
isdnctrl encap ippp0 syncppp
isdnctrl encap ippp1 syncppp
isdnctrl secure ippp0 on
isdnctrl secure ippp1 on
isdnctrl chargehup ippp0 off
isdnctrl addphone ippp0 out outphone
isdnctrl addphone ippp1 out outphone
isdnctrl dialmode ippp0 manual
isdnctrl dialmode ippp1 auto
isdnctrl callback ippp0 off
isdnctrl callback ippp1 off
ifconfig ippp0 -arp -broadcast 
ipppd user myuser \
 defaultroute \
 noipdefault \
 -detach \
 mru 1524 \
 -bsdcomp \
 /dev/ippp0 & sleep 1
isdnctrl dial ippp0
isdnctrl addlink ippp1

#to return to a 64Kbit i USE isdnctrl removelink ippp1
```

Set up a serial modem(TA better) is too easy, is like setup a 56k modem using pppd+chat script
My question is..someone know the command/string to setup the 128k(dual channel) connection with Serial TA on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, we have to modify the chat script and insert the correct line for ppp multilink
For a US robotics 3468 isdn TA is

```
"AT*PPP=3"
```